# VSCode Ctrl + Click

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with VSCode IDE.

Language used: PHP 5.6

IDE Version: 1.19.2

OS: Ubuntu

I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click to go to the function definition.

I have tried setting `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt"` in the settings but that does not help.

Anyone familiar with this issue? Please help.

Comment: Is your file PHPDoc'd? VSCode can (I think) only cross reference functions and classes if you tell it the whole namespaced class in the PHPDoc for each property.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure you have "PHP IntelliSense" Extension and "php.executablePath" set to PHP bin file.

p.s. VSCode is not IDE, it is only code editor and support for PHP is poor.

Comment: "PHP IntelliSense" works for me with no additional config

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! The "PHP IntelliSense" fixed the issue on my machine.

Comment: @gen it's because in most cases "PHP IntelliSense" will find you php.executablePath automatically.

Comment: FTR: for PHP version below 7.4 you can use "DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode" extension - works like a charm

Comment: very appreciated! it worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Remove these settings from setting.json

```
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"
&
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt"
```

Comment: Removing `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"` worked for me on `Lubuntu 20.04 LTS `with `VS Code 1.52.1`. Now, I can open files with `CTRL + Left-click` again.

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone is still having the same issue, I just tried the PHP Intelephense extension by Ben Mewburn and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to go to definition just works without any configuration. [Link to extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. For anybody following the above link, make sure to scroll down to the directions. The plugin won't work if you don't disable specific things in VSCode that the creator calls out.

Answer (score 7):

installing PHP Intelephense extension resolved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Simply install Intelephense extension in VS Code

Answer (score 2):

installing extension reslovle my problem "Path Intellisense"

Comment: How and why does this answer solve the problem? Please be more precise

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not have the .vscode/settings.json file in my project.

so I just added .vscode/settings.json with following content:

```
{
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt"
}
```

config :

- ubuntu 18.04
- vsc 1.59.1

Comment: Also worked on Windows for a javascript web project

Answer (score 1):

I had to install 2 extension in order for VisualStudio Code to parse my code and be able to do Ctrl + click to go to function and ctrl+space to see its docblock.

- PHP IntelliSense
- PHP Namespace Resolver

Answer (score 0):

For my case, its not working when the file is not saved. After I saved the file, and try CTRL + CLICK, it works. Not sure what's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10:

`"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"` setting worked for me in preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a solution for python - Install the Python Intellisense extension and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed "Path Intellisense" and it solved my problem as well!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30803941)

Answer (score 0):

Installing "PHP IntelliSense" worked for me, hope it does for you.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you. Says thanks to the [top voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50988212/5211833)