# How to show a list of class's methods?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to show class's methods when I reference it inside a constructor :

```php
use vendor\Bar;

class Foo{

    private $var;

    public function __construct(Bar $somevar) {
        $this->var = $somevar;
    }

    public function sayHello(){
        $helloMsg = $this->var->**Show a list of Bar's Methods to choose from.**
    }
}
```

in bar.php

```php
class Bar{
    public function hello(){
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

I have tried these extensions but It seems it doesn't do the job :

- php-intellisense
- php-intelephense

Is this possible ?

Comment: May you want to give [ishegg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746485/vscode-ctrl-click) a try.

Comment: Thank you for your help. tried to add PHPDOC for the "constructor" with the namespace of the class as he said ... still no luck!

Comment: @HaaLeo oh I didnt add PHPDOC for the property, and now it works .. thank your for your help.